# What is wrong with the way I am using "turtles-on"?

Tags: syntax, netlogo

I want to model agents moving around, and dying if they reach a patch that already has a # of agents above the carrying capacity (which is determined by a slider).
I tried writting it like this:

```
to check-if-dead
 if habitat = "escarabajo" [
  ask escarabajos [
    if pcolor = one-of [yellow lime orange grey blue ] [die]
      if escarabajos-on patch-here >= capacidad-de-carga-bosques [die] 
    ] 
  ]
```

but I get a message highlighting "escarabajos-on patch-here",and saying > >= expected this input to be an agent or number or string, but got a turtle agentset instead >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `escarabajos-on patch-here` is an agentset: the set of all `escarabajos` on the current patch. What you want is the *number* of `escarabajos` on the current patch, so you need to [`count`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#count) them:

```
if count escarabajos-on patch-here >= capacidad-de-carga-bosques
```

That being said, `escarabajos-on patch-here` is needlessly verbose, since NetLogo also has a [`<breeds>-here`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here) primitive:

```
if count escarabajos-here >= capacidad-de-carga-bosques
```

Finally, I have a hunch that you meant:

```
if member? pcolor [ yellow lime orange grey blue ]
```

instead of:

```
if pcolor = one-of [yellow lime orange grey blue ]
```

The [`one-of`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) primitive picks an element from a list at random, so your condition would have been true only if the randomly picked color happened to be the color of the current patch. By using [`member?`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) instead, the condition will be true if the color of the patch is any member of the list.

Comment: Ahhh!! Great :D Thank you so much